# How to enable syntax color and indention for lwt in Emacs Tuareg mode?

Tags: ocaml, tuareg, ocaml-lwt

I am using Tuareg mode for Emacs.

I am also using `lwt`. `lwt` has some syntax extension, but Tuareg cannot recognize them and it is ugly without indention and coloring.

I found this:

https://github.com/skydeck/lwt/blob/master/utils/tuareg-2.0.4.patch

It is a patch for tuareg-**2.0.4** to enable lwt coloring.

---

However, I am using Tuareg-**2.0.5** and I tried the patch directly, it failed.

I am not sure how to downgrade Tuareg, so I just downloaded the files of tuareg-2.0.4 and copy them to the `elpa/tuareg-2.0.5` folder and then I did the patch again.

This was successfully patched as it said, but still my emacs cannot recognize `lwt`.

---

**Can anyone tell me how**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, you don't have to replace your stock *tuareg.el*.

*1.* Place your patched *tuareg.el* to *~/.emacs.d/* directory

*2.* Add the following lines to your *~/.emacs* config

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(load "tuareg")
```

*3. (Optional)* byte-compile your custom *tuareg.el*

```
M-x byte-compile-file
```

---

Stock tuareg mode

[image: stock tuareg mode]

Tuareg mode with lwt patch

[image: tuareg mode with lwt patch]

Comment: I have to download `tuareg 2.0.4` first, then patch it, then do what you told?